# How to add a zero after "A" character to this string type, "A001" in Excel (convert A001 --->A0001)? Expertise needed

Tags: excel-formula

Problem is i checked out solutions on YouTube and Google, but fail to find the solution.

A001    0A001
A002    0A002
                 [tried this formula, =CONCATENATE(0,H3),but failed to get the 
                 desired result.]

Comment: Just look for some kind of replace command. Then u replace "A" with "A0" and there u go ...

Comment: u seem to be looking for `substitute`

Comment: presume your data starts in cell **A1**, enter this formula in cell B2: `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"00","000")`, and drag it down.

Comment: Thanks buddy. you're awesome! Works like a charm!

Comment: Thanks a million guys! I really appreciate all your input. You're awesome!

Answer (score 0):

You want to Replace "A" with "A0".

IF you want to replace the first occurence of "A" with "A1" then the following function does what you are looking for:

```
=REPLACE(A1;FIND("A";A1);1;"A0")
```

(Under the assumption that the text you want to replace is in the Cell A1)

As @OverflowStacker mentioned substitude would also be an option:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1;"A";"A0")
```

This doesn't seem like the best way to do it, but this would be a workaround if you always want to add a 0 after a character(s) that starts the cell content you can use something like this

```
=IF(MIN(IFERROR(FIND("0";A1);99999);
IFERROR(FIND("1";A1);99999);
IFERROR(FIND("2";A1);99999);
IFERROR(FIND("3";A1);99999);
IFERROR(FIND("4";A1);99999);
IFERROR(FIND("5";A1);99999);
IFERROR(FIND("6";A1);99999);
IFERROR(FIND("7";A1);99999);
IFERROR(FIND("8";A1);99999);
IFERROR(FIND("9";A1);99999))=99999;A1;
SUBSTITUTE(A1;LEFT(A1;
MIN(IFERROR(FIND("0";A1);99999);
IFERROR(FIND("1";A1);99999);
IFERROR(FIND("2";A1);99999);
IFERROR(FIND("3";A1);99999);
IFERROR(FIND("4";A1);99999);
IFERROR(FIND("5";A1);99999);
IFERROR(FIND("6";A1);99999);
IFERROR(FIND("7";A1);99999);
IFERROR(FIND("8";A1);99999);
IFERROR(FIND("9";A1);99999))-1);
CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1;
MIN(IFERROR(FIND("0";A1);99999);
IFERROR(FIND("1";A1);99999);
IFERROR(FIND("2";A1);99999);
IFERROR(FIND("3";A1);99999);
IFERROR(FIND("4";A1);99999);
IFERROR(FIND("5";A1);99999);
IFERROR(FIND("6";A1);99999);
IFERROR(FIND("7";A1);99999);
IFERROR(FIND("8";A1);99999);
IFERROR(FIND("9";A1);99999))-1);"0")))
```

Comment: What about for a row of cells containing similar string type for conversion? B001
                                                                                                                       C003
                                                                                                                       A001

Comment: Thank you Sir for your guidance and assistance. Means a lot to me. Appreciate it!